# How to determine with javascript whether a url that ends with no extensions is a plain image and not a gif?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

I am trying to validate URLs and return false if such URLs happen to return gifs, like these:

- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nxOF05Y28F2WSBPupmOBgTuSxG-GY1BbhZJyOrjVrjKdAax0VTb4_q4_yDnNsFMTdXPZYpmr19nttJ8c1Pzzd835vOEODQGUvcPG
- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/s4a9blztSlDXhjApbdob6CfQ6OUeIiRxb00w9-4Z2Q-6PIp9FGePtI8NBfUfgSgAki3EI2too6zdRyV9qwxdnUWaYLWGgkBa0MN_
- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TJIJhjYUMN2iHsS7Su_WnnfqfbQmJI8y8-zU32-GzYfbDDwofXLMRKk_Q2FTzT096dzDIyptA7-khH2tbCWwbvuWf6V4ITCf3ZncuA
- https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4rIhhfLWqB3qUi-BMkXlyMnylwztk-HfOUQhtsmPBtfJKLh2FPNPMgL3YL6Jg0JMopsMcjaevYjXYw8lR9vFRfrZ2rsV7JXPo6mRVws

However, I cannot use regex as no URL returns something that ends with ".gif".

I have no idea how to verify the format of a file that is returned from a URL, if the said file does not have an extension at the end... may anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You cannot tell without fetching the content at the URL and then evaluating it, or by using some server-side facility to do the same. There is absolutely no meaning to file extensions on the web.

Comment: @Pointy I think I almost solved it. I have read that I can make an HTTP HEAD request to check the content type, so I won't have to download the file. Not sure what the limitations of this approach are...